# T-SQL Wildcard search - namespace values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, patindex

I need to satisfy a condition in a string that has "ns[0-9]:" where [0-9] can be any number even greater than 10.

Example:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE ( value VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @test VALUES
( 'ns1:'),
( 'NOT OK'),
( 'ns7:'),
( 'ns8:'),
( 'ns9:'),
( 'ns10:'), 
( 'ns11:' )


SELECT *, PATINDEX( '%ns[0-9]:%', value ) passes
FROM @test
```

This only works on 1 to 9, not on 10 and above.  I can use [0-9][0-9] but then it only works on 10 and above. I don't want a wild card between the number and the colon either.

I only want the following format to return a 1 with patindex

ns1:, ns2:, ns10:, ns11:, etc.

I also need a non-function solution.  For performance reasons I want to use the string like functionality

Thanks

Comment: Is there ever anything after the `:`, or before the `ns`?

Comment: Your query has % at the beginning of your condition? That changes logic of you query a bit and annuls any performance benefits you were hoping to gain from LIKE operator.

Comment: Yes there will be values before and after 'ns1:'

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
select (case when value like 'ns[0-9]%:' and
                  value not like 'ns[0-9]%[^0-9]%:'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as passes_flag
```

Comment: As the OP's attempt has `':%'` I would be interested to know if there can ever be anything after the `':'` and still have a pass.  In which case `'ns99:this:interests:me'`

Comment: I am hoping to use PATINDEX.  There will be values before and after the 'ns1:' string

Comment: While your solution could solve some cases, my actual use of the PATINDEX function is required.  I have a complex string where 'ns1:' is inside a huge XML string and I need to dynamically tell where the 'ns1:' portion is.

Comment: @MichaelPearson . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  If you have another question, then consider asking it as a *new* question.